# how many block elements in html?

Tags: html, regex

like `<div> <h1>, <p>, <ul>, <table>` are all block elements,anything else? I want to use JavaScript **regx** to replace all block elements with `<br>`

other method to resovle my problem also many thanks.

Comment: What's the reason behind doing this? Also which language you want to use? JavaScript, PHP what?

Comment: Don't use regexp to process HTML. Use a DOM parser.

Comment: You forgot `a`, `article`, `span` and what not

Comment: @hjpotter92 `span`, `a` are inline elements , what he forgets is `aside`, `footer`, `header` and what not

Comment: By "block elements" do you mean "HTML elements with open an closing tags", or "elements that are rendered visually as blocks"?
In the second case you need to check the elements' styles, since anything can be set to `display: inline` or `display:block`

Comment: @Mr.Alien Actually the list depends on the html flavor (4 or 5).

Comment: @Mr.Alien  use javascirpt

Comment: @Christophe `span` and `a` are inline for all versions

Comment: HTML4 Block Elements: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#block - Can't find the same for HTML5, though.

Comment: @Mr.Alien ok. But links have a weird way of being inline in html 5...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN Reference on Block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements)

- `<address>`
- `<article>`
- `<aside>`
- `<audio>`
- `<blockquote>`
- `<canvas>`
- `<dd>`
- `<div>`
- `<dl>`
- `<fieldset>`
- `<figcaption>`
- `<figure>`
- `<footer>`
- `<form>`
- `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>`, `<h5>`, `<h6>`
- `<header>`
- `<hgroup>`
- `<hr>`
- `<noscript>`
- `<ol>`
- `<output>`
- `<p>`
- `<pre>`
- `<section>`
- `<table>`
- `<tfoot>`
- `<ul>`
- `<video>`

This was the #2 item found when googling "HTML block elements" (after a w3fool page). How hard did you try before coming here?